# JQuery add button inside

Tags: jquery

I want to have the below:
 Have a text box(Label Survey Qs), a button(Add Choice), radiobox+ text
 Buttons(Add Button) at the bottom.
When I click on Add Button, new div is getting created (Like Survey2).
When I click on Add Choice(1st one), the new radio+text box is created.

**However when I click on Add Choice(second one), the radio+text box is not created**. The reason is probably the handlers are not associated when we create new objects. But I am  not able to put the live() method to the code to do so.

I am a novice. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Please find my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove textbox example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    div{
        padding:8px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;
    var choiceCounter=2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {
    //$("#addButton").live("click",function () {
    //alert("Inside Click FUnction");
    choiceCounter=0;
    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after('<label>Survey Question '+ counter + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +  '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.append('<label>Survey Question ' + counter + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox'  + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" /> <input type="button" value="Add Choice" id="addOption"> </br><input type="radio"> <input type="textbox" id="option1" ></br>');           
  $('#TextBoxesGroup').append(newTextBoxDiv);  


    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });


     $("#addOption").click(function () {   // the new Add Method
    alert("Inside Option Function");
    if(choiceCounter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + choiceCounter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after( '<br><input type="radio"> <input type="text" name="textbox' + choiceCounter + '" id="option' + choiceCounter + '" value="Insert your choice" >');


    newTextBoxDiv.append( '<br><input type="radio"> <input type="text" name="textbox' + choiceCounter + '" id="option' + choiceCounter + '" value="Insert your choice" />');           
        $('#TextBoxesGroup').append(newTextBoxDiv);  

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    choiceCounter++;
     });





     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">

        <label>Survey Question 1: </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >  <input type="button" value='Add Choice' id="addOption">
        <br><input type="radio"> <input type='textbox' id='option1' ><br>   

    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with delegate event:

```
$("#TextBoxesGroup").on("click", "#addOption", function () { 
  // your code
}):
```

or you can try

```
$("#TextBoxesGroup").delegate("#addOption", "click", function () { 
   // your code
}):
```

#### A little note

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for ordinary binding used like

```
$(target).on(eventName, handlerFunction)
```

But for delegate event (aka live) will use like

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```

Here `container` point to the holder of `target` that belong to DOM at page load. `container` and `target` will be any valid **[jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**.